# Can I use ESP8266 with edgeSDK?

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, raspbian, esp8266, edgeengine

I've started testing edgeSDK in a prototype IOT environment.

The idea is to connect devices with sensors and other nodes (Raspberry Pi, ESP8266, macOS, etc.) and exchange data or messages between them on the edge, trying to avoid communicating through the cloud.

(I will be also "mirroring" this exchanges in an AWS central cloud environment, to establish some comparisons/evaluations).

At this point, I have edgeSDK running on macOS and the Raspberry Pi and would like to add ESP8266 into the mix.

My Question is:
Can I get ESP8266 to work with edgeSDK? I don't see it listed as a supported platform.

If yes, which OS? (I was thinking about Mongoose, keeping the JavaScript coding and follow the standard).

Any other comments/suggestions or similar references would be very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

ESP8266 is a microcontroller, which edgeSDK does not support.  However, you can run a RESTFul API client on ESP8266 to call a API served by a microservice hosted by edgeSDK on a Raspberry Pi for example.